# BQ connector for Excel Error

Tags: excel, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery connector for Excel and receives this error message:

"Request failed: Error. Your query took too long to complete. Abandoning.."

When running the query in the browser tool, it returns under 4 seconds. the query returns ~ 70K records. With some queries that retrieves less data in longer time, I do get the data without errors.
Is this issue is related to Excel? BigQuery? the connector?
Any suggestions how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

We decided to abandon the BQ connector to Excel.
Instead we wrote a python script that retrieves the query results through the API into a csv flat file. and we connect Excel to that flat file.
less elegant... but works.